# Extra `CASE WHEN` Removes Text from Dynamically Created String

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, scripting, ddl

I am trying to generate a `CREATE TABLE` statement based on a given table in my SQL-SERVER database using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables, but when I try and concatenate the `DEFAULT` portion of a field declaration, my code only now displays the field with a `DEFAULT`, despite it being concatenated like the other parts of the field declaration so far.

Consider this Table:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    BAR NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    CREATED_DATE DATETIME DEFAULT (GETDATE())
);
```

The code below generates the statement, but does not take defaults into account, and also assumes you only have one primary key and no foreign keys.
If you add the line that's commented out, it all of a sudden only includes the one field that has a default, and I can't figure out why this is happening.

```sql
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128) = 'FOO'; 
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + ' (' + CHAR(13);
DECLARE @primaryKey NVARCHAR(128) = '';

-- Find primary key
SELECT @primaryKey = COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'PK%';

-- build the string
SELECT @sql = @sql + '  [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] ' + 
    DATA_TYPE + 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NOT NULL THEN '(' + CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR) + ')' 
        WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal', 'numeric') THEN '(' + CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(NUMERIC_SCALE AS VARCHAR) + ')'
        ELSE '' 
    END +
    CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN ' NOT NULL' ELSE ' NULL' END +
    CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = @primaryKey THEN ' PRIMARY KEY' ELSE '' END +
    -- Uncomment below for weird behavior:
    --CASE WHEN COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT ' + UPPER(COLUMN_DEFAULT) ELSE '' END +
    ',' + CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;

-- clean up ending
SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 2) + CHAR(13) + ');';
PRINT @sql;
```

Here is the output with the line commented out (so any `DEFAULT`s are left out):

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
  [ID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  [BAR] nvarchar(50) NULL,
  [CREATED_DATE] datetime NULL
);
```

And then with the line in:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
  [CREATED_DATE] datetime NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE())
);
```

Why is my code generating such different responses?

Comment: I've been messing around in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/55jjRuN2), and curiously, it seems to return correct results when I remove the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) this is antipattern known to return incorrect results:

> Avoid the following pattern for recursive use of variables and expressions:
> syntaxsql
>
> > SELECT @Var = <expression containing @Var>
> >
> > FROM ...
>
> In this case, it isn't guaranteed that @Var would be updated on a row by row basis. For example, @Var may be set to initial value of @Var for all rows. This is because the order and frequency in which the assignments are processed is nondeterminant. This applies to expressions containing variables string concatenation, as demonstrated below, but also to expressions with non-string variables or += style operators.

The documentation continues to suggest using `STRING_AGG` function (which got introduced in SQL Server 2017, so you might be out of luck with your 2016 edition).

I would consider using cursor instead, and building the dynamic SQL field by field.